# Two directories are in the desktop folder, but only one directory is syncing

Tags: synchronization, nitrousio

I placed two folders in the desktop Nitrous.io synced folder.  However, only one of them is syncing to the Nitrous.io Web IDE.

As one can see, the folder named "OrangeLoot front end 2" is in the desktop folder, but it is not syncing to the web IDE.

Update: I changed the name of the file so as to remove the spaces. That didn't seem to help. Still not syncing.

Update: I removed the directory, renamed it to all lowercase letters and pasted the directory back into the synced folder. That didn't help it start syncing.

[image: Screenshot of both Nitrous IDE and synced folder]

Update: 
- I removed the directories from the desktop. Deleted the folders from the IDE side bar.

- Added the directories to the Nitrous server file "blackwater-bay-rails" folder. According to this link/screenshot, directories to be synced should be in this folder: https://www.nitrous.io/desktop#windows
- Refreshed both the IDE sidebar file tree, and the Nitrous desktop.  Still not syncing.

[image: moved my directories inside nitrous server file]

Answer (score 0):

Are your files that are in the "OrangeLoot front end 2" box located within `~/workspace/`? You will need to ensure any files you want to sync are located in this directory within your Nitrous.IO box.

You can also try deleting the folders and re-syncing by clicking **Sync Now** within the Nitrous Desktop app.